# Swiperjs Custom Pagination in the loop

Tags: jquery, loops, pagination, swiper.js

I've found here on stack how to create custom pagination for swiperjs and the code is like this:

```
new Swiper('.swiper', {
  pagination: {
    el: '.pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return `<span class="dot swiper-pagination-bullet">${index}</span>`;
    },
  },
});
```

This works perfeclty so thanks to: @Антон Булгаков for this solution.
But i just wonder is there posibility to create this pagination in the loop same as swiper is in the loop? Like this:

```
new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop:true,
  pagination: {
    el: '.pagination',
    clickable: true,
    renderBullet: function (index, className) {
      return `<span class="dot swiper-pagination-bullet">${index}</span>`;
    },
  },
});
```

The problem is that currently swiper (slides) are in the loop but not the pagination and i would like to pagination also in the loop.

Comment: It is not make sense (The loop duplicate slides - renderBullet loop runs only related to the visibile slides). No way to solve this (You can add your own logic - but it is risky to destroy the slider logic.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've currently don't have additional time to solve this on my own but if i do i'll post it as an answer.